# Client-side Library installed using Libman does not show in solution explorer of Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc, client-side, libman

I installed jquery-validate using Libman but the file does not appear in solution explorer of visual studio 2017. I have attached an image of the window which shows the installed client side library not showing in solution explorer. Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0alAQ.png)

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue.Did you try to rebuild the project and check if your network is connected or not?

Comment: i did rebuild the project as well as reinstall jquery-validate several times. The file name appears in libman.json but not in solution explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I had two jQuery libraries, so when removing one jQuery library, I could install the jquery-validate libraries.

Answer (score 0):

In your `EmployeeManagementSystem.csproj` file, delete the following line:

```xml
<Compile Remove= "wwwroot\lib\jquery-validate\**" />
```